# trying to pass char array as an argument in java and getting Index error

Tags: java, arrays, char

I'm trying to draw and initialize 2d array, when all my code is in main method there is no error but i split my code to methods and i had index error.

This is my method :

```
public static void initializeTable(char[][] table ) {

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
             table[i][j] = 'S';   //this is line 90 where the error occurs i think.
        }
    }
}
```

How i use it in main :

```
    public class Cinema {
    public static int row, column,x,y;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        char[][] table = new char[row][column];

        enterRowColumn();
        initializeTable(table); //line 15
    }
}
```

And error message :

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
    at cinema.Cinema.initializeTable(Cinema.java:90)
    at cinema.Cinema.main(Cinema.java:15)
```

Comment: could you post entire code

Comment: Well, `row` and `column` are not sync with the exact length from table. Either `table` has length equals to zero or `table[j]` has length equals to zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Default value for primitive numbers is `0`.

```
public static int row, column,x,y;
```

Those all are initialized as zeroes. Then you create array

```
char[][] table = new char[row][column];
```

before you assign other values, and array looks like `char[0][0]`.

Move the array initialization **after** you assign values to `row` and `column`

Comment: Problem solved! Thank you very much. i kinda feel like a stupid for not noticing that but i'm beginner who trying to learn new thing every day. Thanks again!

Comment: @toprakunal Everybody has those moments, experienced developers as well... Keep learning :)

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException by iterating using the array's state.

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < table.length ; ++i) {
  for (int j = 0 ; j < table[i].length ; ++j) {
    ...
  }
}
```

However, that still leaves you with the logical error of creating the table before knowing the dimensions.  Basically change the order of these operations.

```
enterRowColumn()
char[][] table = new char[row][column];
```

p.s. kudos for using methods to do things rather than doing everything in your main method.

Comment: great advice, i understand now why most of programmers using the array's state. Can you briefly explain why you use plus sign before "i" ? I get used to use after "i" is there any significant difference between these? and thanks for p.s. :)

Comment: @toprakunal many moons ago there was an insignificant performance benefit to using pre-increment rather than post-increment, however, I don't know if that still holds.  At this point it is just habit/personal-preference.